# postgis installation gone awry

Tags: postgresql-9.3, postgis

[cross-posted from stack ove
On a Ubuntu 14.04 staging server a MySQL connection protocol had to be installed for full-text searching for a separate application.  This led to installing, uninstalling ad installing anew mysql and sphinxsearch.

After a reboot, another application hits an error because:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1": No such file or directory
```

in psql (version 9.3.10) the same error message is getting confirmed upon

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

notwithstanding that a check on the database returns `extension "postgis" already exists`.. `whereis postgis` also returns a blank.

Has postgis been somehow uninstalled?

Attempting to install anew:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis
```

getting `Package postgresql-9.3-postgis is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source E: Package 'postgresql-9.3-postgis' has no installation candidate`

Even attempting to create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`with

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
```

then

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis
```

getting the same no installation candidate. Is this server hosed for postgis now?  Would re-installing postgresql impact existing applications on the VPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1

Comment: wonderful scroll of `Setting up...` App ran.  Therefore something in the uninstall process of MySQL tripped up postgis...